# Can Janus WebRTC server implement server-side peer?

Tags: webrtc, rtp, janus-gateway

I've been reading about [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/), looked at the examples. I'm looking for a webRTC component that I can use in the following way:

1. Receive RTP video packets from some external sender
2. Become a WebRTC peer and connect to an external WebRTC signaling server, STUN, TURN, the usuals
3. Send the incoming RTP packets as a coherent video via the WebRTC peer connection to some other peer on a browser on the Internet

Is Janus the right tool? Maybe there are other tools? Would appreciate some directions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Janus.

You can achieve these functionalities with LM Tools (lmtools.com) with easy configuration. It can receive RTP packets from external sender and can send those packets as per WebRTC specification to other peer.

Please note LM tools is not free software like JSON, though you can have free trial for 1 month.

Disclaimer: I work for LM Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Can Janus WebRTC server implement server-side peer?

- Yes, can can do that. What you are looking for is an RTP forwarding and you will get more context, and expert opinion from their [community friendly google group page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meetecho-janus/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for a Gateway solution.

(RTP/RTCP separate streams are converted to webrtc RTP/RTCP mux)

For this you need to make changes in the Janus code or use some plugin supporting RTP/RTSP.

Current Janus server relays RTP/RTCP and messages between browsers.
https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/